# Tableau Desktop : Use of COUNTD

Tags: tableau-api

my data is presented as follow.

```
Col1 Col2
A   x
A   x
A   y
B   x
C   z
```

I simply want to represent Column 1 on a graph in the X axis with the number of unique references to of the data in Column 2 as Y axis.

Basically my graph would be like A (2) ;  B (1) ; C (1).

I'm not sure how to use COUNTD on that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Place `Col1` in the Columns shelf.

Place `COUNTD(Col2)` in the Rows shelf. (Put `Col2` in the Rows shelf, then right click it and select **Measure / Count (Distinct)**.)

That will give you a bar chart by default. If you'd rather have a table, place `COUNTD(Col2)` into the Text shelf instead.

Answer (score 1):

Place `Col1` on the Rows shelf and `Number of Records` measure in Text/value.